# Pass JIRA variables to Bamboo on release

Tags: bitbucket, jira, bamboo

We have JIRA, BitBucket and Bamboo, all integrated running locally on a server.
I would like to have Bamboo build my software when I decide to release it in JIRA.

There is a document available at Atlassian that describes this:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/running-a-bamboo-build-when-releasing-a-version-764478184.html

The problem is that my interface doesn't have the *Build Variables* as described in the documentation. This is crucial, because I want JIRA to pass the version number and Bamboo to use that as a variable for different tasks.

Here is a screenshot of the interface:
[image: JIRA release UI]

I realise that the docs are for JIRA cloud, but seeing that the same interface is available on the server edition, I would expect to be able to accomplish the same thing.

We use JIRA version 7.9.2 and Bamboo version 6.5.1

Does anyone know why the Build Variables might be missing, or how else to tackle passing variables from JIRA to Bamboo in a self-hosted situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by using the "Dump variables to log" job to check what variables are available. As it turns out the JIRA version is available when a build is triggered through the JIRA "release" button.

The variable I could use is `bamboo.jira.version`.

This doesn't solve the actual problem of defining arbitrary variables in JIRA and passing them on to Bamboo, but it solves the problem in my use-case, as I was looking to pass the release version.

***Update***:

I have an offical answer form Atlassian regarding this question.

I was under the impression that the custom variables you want to pass are defined on the release screen in JIRA itself.

As it turns out, variables are defined on the *plan* or *global* level in *Bamboo*, and they can then be used/overridden on the release screen in JIRA.

It works now!
[image]